# Load polygon in Google map api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to implement like user can draw a area in google map from our application.
Then when he come back, then should load the data which is previously drew by him/her.

I've done two way of method. One is,

1. Using Drawing manager.

   [Drawing Polygon in google map using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679291/drawing-polygon-in-google-map-using-javascript)

   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer
2. Using Google map api data layer. `http://jsfiddle.net/dg9e93qy/`

**From the first method,** I can allow user to drag, and can restrict user from drawing multiple polygons.
**But I cannot load the polygons again to this drawing.**
But I found somewhere that we can load the polygons. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple.

But this is using the polygon instance to show the polygons not the drawing.

Here I need any other two solutions.

- Whether I should load the polygon data to the map using drawing.
- Should enable drawing option using polygon `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple`

**From the Second method,** I can get the coordinates, and can load the polygon again. But I cannot get the polygon area from that. (Actually I am getting the geoJson data)

Here I cannot get the Area for Drawn place.
How to do that?

Any answer from the first method or the second methods is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done alternate that, created polygon instead of loading in the same drawing manager.

After drawing complete, removed drawing manager and then created the polygon. Then had a separate button to remove the polygon from the map.

If we remove the polygon, then removed the polygon from the map and recreated the drawing manger.

This solved my issue.

```
drawingManager.setMap(null);
                    bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                        paths: polygonsArray,
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                        fillOpacity: 0.35
                        //,editable: true
                    });
                    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```